# How to display list like string in templates?

Tags: django

How to display list like string in templates?

```
 Yeah!{{msg}}
```

Example output:

> Yeah! ['You have successfully changed this!']

I need display this in this way:

> Yeah! You have successfully changed this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first element of the list:

```
{{ msg.0 }}
```

If your list exists of more items you could display them all by looping over them:

```
{% for item in msg %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Yeah! {% for m in msg %}{{m}}{% endfor %}
```

This way, if you have multiple messages in the list, you can show everything